# python3,i print chinese in windows cmd,it will be automatically wrap and add two symbols

Tags: python, windows, console

I have to change the encoding using chcp 65001 utf-8,and the chinese display is correct,but it will be automatically wrap and add two symbols.

My Python code:

[image: my python code]

My Windows console:

[image: windows console]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't
be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your
question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four
spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: You have to include both the Python version and Windows version. Both have undergone significant changes in recent versions with respect to console I/O.